# Is it possible to wrap a <picture> element inside a <a>?

Tags: html

I'm messing with performance in a website and I have include  elements and the picture Polyfill. I need this pictures to be a link as they are the logo to the home website. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

I have tried wrapping this to a  but this doesn't work (do not show any images).

```html
<a class="site-header" href="">
  <picture class="isologo">
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcset="image-big.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)" />
    <source srcset="image.jpg" media="(min-width: 320px)" />
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="Sample pic" />
  </picture>
  <picture class="brand">
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcset="image-big-2.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)" />
    <source srcset="image-2.jpg" media="(min-width: 320px)" />
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="Sample pic" />
  </picture>
</a>
```

I expected both pictures to be a link.

Comment: Your HTML has errors in it. Do some minimal automated testing: https://validator.nu/

Comment: When I test it, both alt texts (because the images are broken) are perfectly functional links.

Comment: In your `<img>` tag, the `srcset="..."`, I think it should be `src="..."`

Comment: If it works in the snippet and not in your project, then chances are you've inadvertently changed something while creating your minimal example, what is the exact failing code in your project? Or if it is identical, what other code is wrapping/or having an effect on it?

Comment: thanks guys! I think i have cache issues with the real images, or rendering issues. It works for me as it is. The srcset is ok for me.